# How can I sort by "updated_date desc" with the gem 'acts_as_taggable_on_steroids'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using

This fetches 10 tags of the most pupular tags

```
@tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags, :limit => 10, :order => "count desc")
```

This fetches 10 tags of the oldest tags

```
@tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags, :limit => 10)
```

How can I fetch 10 tags of the newest tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about sorting via id and get the newest?

@tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags, :limit => 10, :order => "id asc")